# How to include an online forms in a sphinx-build website

Tags: python, forms, python-sphinx

I have a python package and website which is build with `sphinx`. I'm looking to include a page containing a form that can be filled:

```
e-mail (*):
question 1:
question 2:
...

Validate
```

Upon validation, the form should be converted in a nice formatting and sent by mail.
Before writing my own tool and extension, do you know of any sphinx extension I could use to do so?

Comment: This is a pure JavaScript issue and thus orthogonal to Sphinx/rst. I'm unaware of any Sphinx extension offering that functionality because extensions are focused on rst. Themes normally include extended rst/JS interaction but what you're asking for doesn't pertain to a theme nor to rst so you'll have to search for a JS solution and include it in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You embed HTML in any Sphinx page with the [`raw`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) directive.

- Create your form in Google Forms or similar
- Embed it to a Sphinx page using HTML and `<iframe>`

Basic HTML knowledge is required.